# Int crash my app

Tags: android, math, int

I am wondering if there is any issue with the line below?

```
  int b1 = Integer.valueOf(selection.getText().toString());
  int b12 =  (b1*100);
  result.setText(Integer.toString(b12));
```

I have isolated the line to the line below:

```
int b1 = Integer.valueOf(selection.getText().toString());
```

I am intending to use the b1 int value to do a simple math which is shown in the line below :

```
int b12 =  (b1*100);
```

and follow by output the value to a `TextView` name result

```
result.setText(Integer.toString(b12));
```

I found some answer and try out in stackoverflow but don't seen to 
help. can any kind soul enlighten me?

Below are the log after I change the code given by K Neeraj Lal

```
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862): Process: com.lockon.smdresistor2, PID: 7862
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lockon.smdresistor2/com.lockon.smdresistor2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "TextView"
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "TextView"
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:489)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at com.lockon.smdresistor2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
05-26 23:11:29.542: E/AndroidRuntime(7862):     ... 11 more
```

K Neeraj Lah and guys maybe this will help abit

```
selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text0);  
  Spinner spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner0);  
  result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

  spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

  ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

  aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  spin.setAdapter(aa);
```

Comment: Post your stack trace please.

Comment: it's probably because `selection` doesn't contain a String which represents an int

Comment: the spinner contain 0-9 and R. will it affect it? but this R is need in my app

Comment: If it's non-numeric, it will crash the app.

Comment: any suggest? cause i will need the R later in the stage of the app completion

Comment: Dear all, i just remove the R from my spinner and it still crash

Comment: what is the class type of 'selection' ?

Comment: selection is not a class, ,its a textview

Comment: Can you add at the beginning: `System.out.println(selection.getText());`, and tell us what is the output just before the crash? Also, what is the error message, please?

Comment: where are should put this?

Comment: Why is the `selection` a string? It should be a number.

Comment: the app just crash right away nothing is shown. i read the log cat and believe is this line : int b1 = Integer.valueOf(selection.getText().toString());

Comment: K Nerraj Lal i added some more code maybe will have some help to understand it better

Comment: what number do you type in this textview?

Comment: the value is taken from a spinner ranging 0-9 and a R inside the spinner. even if i remove the R from the spinner it will still crash

Comment: Seems like when you get the text of your textview (int: selection.getText() ) is still a simple text; "TexView". Of course the system doesn't know how to parse this into an int. Where you are changing this value?
What happen if your add this line before,, just for test purposes:
selection.setText("1");

Comment: i added your code and remove all other code with the int line and the app run fine. your line dont have much affect too.

Comment: mayo i added back my int codes and with your and my android is working fine just that the value will alway be 1 * 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are sure that you are getting an int value in *Selection Textview* you can try this out:

```
int b1 = Integer.parseInt(selection.getText().toString());
int b12 = b1 * 100;
result.setText(String.valueOf(b12));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
try{
    String text = selection.getText().toString();
    int b1 = 0;
    if(!text.equals("") || isIntegerParseInt(text)){
        b1  = Integer.valueOf();
        int b12 =  (b1*100);
        result.setText(Integer.toString(b12));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please input a number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
....

public static boolean isIntegerParseInt(String str) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(str);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {}
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: still crash. anything that i can provide to help solve this issue?

Comment: Can you put the log? With that we will have more info !

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 way

```
result.setText(String.valueOf(b12));
```

and

```
result.setText(b12 + "");
```

the problem i have in my case seen to my R file is having some bug with the selection textview so i have did a clean to my project and remove the R and recreate the R file again